# How to dynamically retranslate all widgets in application through a menu?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, translation

I am working on a Qt project consisting in a `QMainWindow` and multiple Qt and non-Qt classes. Many of them use QStrings with `tr()` that are translated with Qt Linguist. The language change (`QTranslator` load & install/`QTranslator` load & remove) is triggered by QActions in the app's menu.

I have read [the official Qt documentation concerning dynamic translation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html#dynamic-translation), and it basically suggests the following overload:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
        titleLabel->setText(tr("Document Title"));
        ... // all my tr() QStrings here
        okPushButton->setText(tr("&OK"));
    } else
        QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the QStrings to translate are many (58 in `QMainWindow` alone), and several are filled at runtime as well, through user interaction; e. g. `myFunction(a,b)` below is called through a `QPushButton`:

```
void MainWindow::myFunction(MyClassA a, MyClassB b)
            {
            ...
            if(b.myCondition() == 0)
                {
                ...
                // below is the problem
                myLabel->setText(myLabel->text() + QString("\n" + a->getName() + tr(" gagne ") + exp + tr(" points d'expérience")));
                }
             else
             {
                myLabel->setText(QString(tr("something else")));
             }
            ...
            }
```

So I hardly see how I can include this type of `QString` in the `changeEvent()` method above. What about the classes outside of `MainWindow`, which also have QStrings to translate but are not `QWidget` (so no `changeEvent` overload possible) ?

I have read that there's another way to use this method, with a UI form:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
        ui.retranslateUi(this);
    }
...
}
```

But this involves that I am using a UI form in my project, which I am not doing (all widgets are created in code).
I tried to export my MainWindow in a UI form, but when I try to include the generated header into the project, I get the following error:

```
ui_fenetreprincipale.h:32: error: qmainwindowlayout.h: No such file or directory
```

Thank you by advance for any suggestion to select the best way to translate my application.

Answer (score 3):

Organize your code so that all the setting of translatable strings is done in one method in each class.

eg give every class that has translatable strings a setTrs() method that actually sets the strings.

```
class A 
{
   void setTrs()
   { 
     okPushButton->setText(tr("&OK"));    
   }
}
//--------------
class B
{
   int _trCond;
   void myFunction(MyClassA a, MyClassB b)
   {
        _trCond = b.myCondition(); 
        setTrs();
   }

   void setTrs()
   {
         if(_trCond == 0)
            myLabel->setText(myLabel->text() + QString("\n" + a->getName() + tr(" gagne ") + exp + tr(" points d'expérience")));
         else
            myLabel->setText(QString(tr("something else")));
   }
```

Then whenever the language for the application changes (eg connect to a menu entry selection, or MainWindow::event() or however the required language can change), you have to manually call the `setTrs` method of each of these objects

eg

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
   if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) 
   {
        setTrs();
        objA.setTrs();
        objB.setTrs();
    }
}
```

Even more elegant would be to store the objects in a QList and just iterate through it calling the `setTrs` method on each element in turn

Comment: This is indeed how code generated by Qt Designer works, as well. The function name is different (`retranslateUi`) but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, menus not translating, fixed completely by creating and installing the QTranslator...

```
QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(new QApplication(argc, argv));
QTranslator myappTranslator;
myappTranslator.load(QString("Languages/de"))
app->installTranslator(&myappTranslator);
```

...before creating and showing the main window...

```
MainWindow *mainWin;
mainWin = new MainWindow(&splash);
mainWin->show();
```